# reading char data from binary file with numpy

Tags: python, string, numpy, binaryfiles

I have a binary file with some character data stuck in the middle of a bunch of ints and floats.  I am trying to read with numpy.  The farthest I have been able to get regarding the character data is:

`strbits = np.fromfile(infile,dtype='int8',count=73)`

(Yes, it's a 73-character string.)

Three questions: Is my data now stored without corruption or truncation in strbits?  And, can I now convert strbits into a readable string?  Finally, should I be doing this in some completely different way?

UPDATE:
Here's something that works, but I would think there would be a more elegant way.

```
strarr = np.zeros(73,dtype='c')
for n in range(73):
   strarr[n] = np.fromfile(infile,dtype='c',count=1)[0]
```

So now I have an array where each element is a single character from the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're doing it is fine. Here's how you can convert it to a string.

```
strbits = np.fromfile(infile, dtype=np.int8, count=73)
a_string = ''.join([chr(item) for item in strbits])
```